# How to trigger an application running on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We plan to run a java application on Elastic BeanStalk. It is noting but a file retriever, processor, transformer and a mapper. It would retrieve the file from S3 and map it to an RDS DB. Question is how do I trigger this application running on beanstalk on file arrival on S3 bucket and also on demand ?

Thanks and regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 1):

You can send an event to SNS (notification topic)  on S3 file upload.

Then I see two options:

To the SNS you can hook up a lambda or http invocation, however in that case you will need to handle failures or availability issues.

If your application is running on EC2 I'd suggest to send the upload event to SQS (queue service) and your application can poll for queue messages

> also on demand

for that you need to expose a an interfate or service from your application. You did not specify what your application is, so it's really up to you to define what 'on demand' is

Comment: Thanks @gusto2, The application is Java code to process an incoming file, validate it against some pre-defined logic and insert to database. I understood the S3 trigger part rather that was the route I was taking and thanks for re-affirming that. Now for the on-demand trying to think out loud our choices.
1) What if we fake the file arrival to S3 ?
2) If we are able to leverage a sheduler then is there a way to trigger and EB application ?